# ISERROR - Too many arguments - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to place the following function into an excel cell; however, I am told that their are too many arguments in the function.

Here is the function:=IF(ISERROR(M12/SUM(E12:I12),0, M12/SUM(E12:I12))

Is this possible? If so, what changes do I make?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: try: `=IF(ISERROR(M12/SUM(E12:I12)),0, M12/SUM(E12:I12)`

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a `)` for the ISERROR:

```
 =IF(ISERROR(M12/SUM(E12:I12)),0, M12/SUM(E12:I12))
```

But your formula can be simplified with the use of IFERROR instead:

```
=IFERROR(M12/SUM(E12:I12),0)
```